# react-native upgrade returning 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to update my react native to latest version. I run the command: `react-native upgrade --verbose`

However, it is returning:

```
info No version passed. Fetching latest...
info Fetching diff between v0.59.8 and v0.60.5...
error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
debug TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at getPatch (/Users/myUser/Documents/React Native/myApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/upgrade/upgrade.js:109:121)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

How can I upgrade react native?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the caches and/or delete node_modules and reinstall it ?

Comment: Yes, still not working

Answer (score 9):

Add the name attribute in your package.json file. this will resolve the issue

Comment: Which attribute?

Comment: Add name: "appname" in your package.json file

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new with React Native, could you please give me an example? What is "appname"?

Comment: You can keep anything as name to make it work basically name is your app name.

Comment: This worked! Add "name": "{your-project-name}" in the package.json file